# show graph on using google chart api

Tags: javascript, php, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to create pie chart using google chart api. It has no issue, and shows perfectly when testing on localhost.

But when I put entire code on my ec2 linux instance. It create chart box, gives title but chart is not drawn. What can be the mistake?

data is taken from mysql databaase. I checked table and it's content, but it is same as on my localhost.

url.php

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>ThenWat</title>

    <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
     <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);    


    function drawVisualization(dataFromAjax) {

    var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "ajax_graph_temp.php",
          dataType:"json",
          async: false
          }).responseText;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
        var options = {
           title: 'Index analysis',
          is3D: 'true',
          width: 800,
          height: 600
        };
        alert("");
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('txtHint'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
         }
function makeAjaxCall() {
      $.ajax({url:'url.php',
              data: {},
              success: function(responseData) {
                         drawVisualization();
                       }
        });
    }
     </script>
   </head>
   <body style="height: 560px">
           <img alt="" src= "3.png" style="top: 38px; right: 689px; position: absolute; height: 91px; width: 417px"/>
               <form action="data.php" method="POST" onsubmit="showUser(this, event)">
            <div style="z-index: 1; left: 470px; top: 100px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">              
               <label>Enter URL: <input type="text" name="sent"></label><br/>
            </div>
            <div style="z-index: 1; left: 420px; top: 160px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">  <button> Fire me </button>      
            </div>
         </form>
         <div style="z-index: 1; left: 660px; top: 160px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px"> 
            <button onclick="makeAjaxCall(); return false;" value="View Graph" > View Graph </button>
         </div>

         <div id="txtHint" style="z-index: 1; left: 220px; top: 250px; position: absolute; margin-top: 0px">        
         </div>

   </body>
</html>
```

ajax_graph_temp.php

```
<?php
$mysqli =mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1:3306', 'root', 'root', 'test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
}
  $result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM view_name');

  $rows = array();
  $table = array();
  $table['cols'] = array(
    array('label' => 'pcount', 'type' => 'string'),
    array('label' => 'ncount', 'type' => 'number')
);
    /* Extract the information from $result */
    foreach($result as $r) {
      $temp = array();
      $temp[] = array('v' => (string) $r['ind_type']); 
      $temp[] = array('v' => (int) $r['Index_val']); 
      $rows[] = array('c' => $temp);
    }

$table['rows'] = $rows;

// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable = json_encode($table);
echo $jsonTable;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that you have your code set up, you are making two AJAX calls, the first of which doesn't seem to accomplish anything:

```
function makeAjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({url:'url.php',
        data: {},
        success: function(responseData) {
            drawVisualization();
        }
    });
}
```

Do you have a "url.php" for that AJAX call to query?  If not, then your success function will never fire, and thus never call `drawVisualization`.  Unless you have other plans for this function, you could simplify your code like this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

function drawVisualization(dataFromAjax) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(dataFromAjax);
    var options = {
        title: 'Index analysis',
        is3D: 'true',
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('txtHint'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
function makeAjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "ajax_graph_temp.php",
        dataType:"json",
        success: drawVisualization
    });
}
```

Comment: Should it not be `success: function(json) { drawVisualization(json);}` ? - or `success : drawVisualization(json)` ?

Comment: You could do the first, but not the second.  `success: drawVisualization(json)` would call the `drawVisualization` function and pass its return value to `success`.  It would work only if `drawVisualization` returned a function.